# Flutter, how to use exist Bloc for other screens?

Tags: flutter, flutter-dependencies, bloc, cubit

Assume that class A is arbitrarily rooted, and its children are classes B, C, and D.

(Not all classes are in the same hierarchy)

When I use BlocConsumer or BlocBuilder in class D, I get an error.

I just want to reuse the Bloc state used in class A and class B.

is there any solutions? thanks

--UPDATE

I am talking about this https://github.com/felangel/bloc/issues/74

Is there any way other than passing it as navigator argument to class one by one?

Comment: At least show us code with what we can see the scope of your `BlocProvider`...

Comment: @SimonSot Sorry of course I can copy and paste but I think this explanation is way more clean. I'm just talking about the complete basic structure. I wanted to say that class A uses BlocProvider and B allows Bloc Consumer, but C and D cannot. I just wanted to explain this

Answer (score 0):

Note: I assume you are using the `flutter_bloc` library, but the concept is the same even though you are not.

The BLoC you want to access must be provided ABOVE all the screens/pages you want to access this BLoC in. The simplest solution to your problem would be wrapping your root Widget (probably `MaterialApp`) with `BlocProvider`:

```
runApp(
  BlocProvider<YourBloc>(
    create: (_) => YourBloc(), // create your BLoC here
    child: MaterialApp(...),
  ),
);
```

For more info, I would recommend watching this video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=laqnY0NjU3M

Comment: hi what if the parent is not in the main method? I have A TabBarClass and it provides BlocProvider and then each tab bar screen view can use BlocConsumer or BlocBuilder however, the tab bar screen view`s childrens are not able to use BlocBuilder or BlocConsumer

Comment: Not sure if that could be a problem - if you provide the BLoC above the e.g. MaterialApp, it should be accessible in all the internal pages despite where you keep them.

Answer (score 0):

introduce blocprovider on main myapp page and use it on other pages