# Lazy instantiate blocks with BlocProvider.value

Tags: flutter, dart, routes, bloc, flutter-bloc

I'm using Generated Routes with Flutter, and I would like to [share blocs between them](https://bloclibrary.dev/#/recipesflutterblocaccess?id=generated-route-access).

But I think that maybe the example solution might not scale the best, since the blocs are instantiated with the router.

Is there a way to instantiate them only when the user access that route?

```dart
class AppRouter {
  final _counterBloc = CounterBloc();

  Route onGenerateRoute(RouteSettings settings) {
    switch (settings.name) {
      case '/':
        return MaterialPageRoute(
          builder: (_) => BlocProvider.value(
            value: _counterBloc,
            child: HomePage(),
          ),
        );
      case '/counter':
        return MaterialPageRoute(
          builder: (_) => BlocProvider.value(
            value: _counterBloc,
            child: CounterPage(),
          ),
        );
      default:
        return null;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: If you are sharing blocs between all your routes, build them above your `Navigator`.

Comment: Wouldn't it generate lots of boilerplate?

Comment: Why would it generate boilerplate?

Comment: I thought I would need to use something like define it as null and then check if null to instantiate on every route, but seems that I can use `late` declaration on it to instantiate it only when called.

Comment: Why would you need to instantiate it on every route? Every route is pointing to the same bloc, right? Then wrap your `Navigator` in a `BlocProvider` so that every route implicitly has access to it. Don't even worry about messing it on a per-route basis.

Comment: Does this answer your question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67585543/flutter-how-to-use-exist-bloc-for-other-screens/67588687?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Got it! Flutter has a new keyword called `late` to do this without any boilerplate.

```dart
class AppRouter {
  late final CounterBloc _counterBloc = CounterBloc();

  Route onGenerateRoute(RouteSettings settings) {
    switch (settings.name) {
      case '/':
        return MaterialPageRoute(
          builder: (_) => BlocProvider.value(
            value: _counterBloc,
            child: HomePage(),
          ),
        );
      case '/counter':
        return MaterialPageRoute(
          builder: (_) => BlocProvider.value(
            value: _counterBloc,
            child: CounterPage(),
          ),
        );
      default:
        return null;
    }
  }
}
```

That's why we love flutter!

Reference: [What is Null Safety in Dart?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60068435/what-is-null-safety-in-dart)